VBA - Save email object (OLEFormat) to file from clipboard
I'm trying to have a drag-and-drop functionality for dragging emails from Outlook into Excel and saving to a folder. This is part of a larger macro which records information and uploads it to a server. There is no easy way to do it, but I think I've almost cracked it. I'm at the stage where I can get something that works - but takes too long and is easily interruptible by the user.
My Excel VBA code performs the following steps:

Open a new Word instance and creates a new document
Monitor the document's WordApp_WindowSelectionChange event which fires when an email is dragged and dropped onto the document.
Check whether the WordApp_WindowSelectionChange event fired because an email was embedded.
If it was an email then copy the embedded email (which is in OLEFormat) onto the clipboard. In the case that it wasn't an email, do nothing.
Close the Word document and app once the email is copied to the clipboard.'
Open an explorer window using Shell and pausing to allow the window to open.
Paste the email to an Explorer window using sendkeys: Applicaiton.sendkeys "^v".

This code actually works! But it's slow in that an Explorer window has to open, and worse, if the user clicks and sets the focus window elsewhere whilst Excel is waiting for the Explorer window to open, the Application.Sendkeys message goes elsewhere and the whole thing fails.
What I would like to do is just get the OLEFormat email directly from the clipboard and save it using VBA. I have found many solutions which do this for images or other file types but can't find one that works for emails. Can anybody please help?
FYI, I have earlier tried using Excel to directly save the OLEFormat email using Outlook but my security settings don't allow that. If anybody has an alternative method which works without using the clipboard, I'd be happy to consider that. My main constraint is that it must be doable from Excel using VBA.

Why close the word app so soon? Keep it open and only when the explorer is open, copy the embedded email onto the clipboard and instantly paste? Once everything is done, then close the word app? Also if you can share more details about the explorer then perhaps we can use APIs instead of Sendkeys?

Could you add a folder to Outlook, and save any MailItems that are dropped into it?

@siddharth Im currently using Shell("explorer.exe folder path"). I don't have a handle on it and can't tell when it's loaded - I just wait 3 seconds. It's not a great method because after the user drags and drops, if they click anything at the wrong moment then that explorer wondow will lose focus and not get the send keys message. Regarding closing the word app, it doesn't matter when I close it - the email is already on the clipboard. Unless I'm missing something?

@tinman I can't use Outlook because my security settings won't let me use the mailitem.saveas function.

Can you share the exact code that you are using?

I'm update my question with the code as soon as I have a chance. At the moment, it's literally the bones to test whether I can make drag and drop off emails work.

Calling the WinAPI SetForegroundWindow function before using sendkeys should solve the issue of the user changing the focused window.  It is also possible to pre-open the Explorer window and hide/show it using WinAPI.
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
#End If

Sub SetForegroundWindowByTitle(windowTitle As String)
    Dim hWnd As LongPtr
    ' Find the window handle based on the window title
    hWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, windowTitle)
    
    If hWnd <> 0 Then
        ' Set the found window as the foreground window
        SetForegroundWindow hWnd
    Else
        Debug.Print "Window not found: " & windowTitle
    End If
End Sub

WebBrowser1 as a File Explorer (FileView)
I'm not clear why MS Word is being used (presumable to capture the Drag and Drop events), or why the user doesn't simply drag the files into the File Explorer.  Another alternative would be to use a WebBrower control on a Userform as a File Explorer (FileView).

With this simple setup, we can get a list of the Emails being dropped into the WebBrowser.

Option Explicit
Private WithEvents FolderView As Shell32.ShellFolderView

Private Sub FolderView_SelectionChanged()
    ListBox1.Clear
    Dim Item As FolderItem2
    
    For Each Item In FolderView.SelectedItems
        If Item.Type = "Outlook Item" Then
            If Item.ExtendedProperty("System.DateCreated") > Now - TimeValue("00:00:01") / 4 Then
                ListBox1.AddItem Item.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim Document
    
    WebBrowser1.Navigate "file:///D:/vba/test_WebBrowser"
    While WebBrowser1.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Set FolderView = WebBrowser1.Document
    
End Sub

Note: It is possible to embed a WebBrowser control into a Worksheet but we need to modify the registry todo so.
Download WebBrowser as a FileView Test
Note: Set Userform ShowModal = False to allow dragging and dropping of the email or files.

Thank you! I tested this and it works. For what it's worth, the reason I was using Word as my drag and drop window was because from my googling, I'd seen other forum responses saying there was no way to get drag and drop for emails working in Excel. Hence the rabbit hole I went down with Word. The reason I didn't want to drag and drop straight into the File Explorer was there isn't (or at least to my knowledge) a method of automatically executing a VBA macro when dragging an email to File Explorer.

Here is my test file:  Download WebBrowser as a FileView Test.  You'll be able to respond to the dragging an email to File Explorer with it.  Thanks for accepting my answer @user1357607!

I'd like to implement this solution on Powerpoint but I can't seem to get it working - the same code doesn't work for me when it did in Excel. The problem is that the Webbrowser1/Folderview doesn't seem to accept drag and drops of files or emails. Is this a shortcoming of Powerpoint or is there additional code I can use to force it to accept the drag and drop files?

@user1357607 Set Userform ShowModal = False to allow dragging and dropping of the email or files.
